# Maximum limit of unique permissions that can be set to SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, list-item, item-level-permissions

What is the maximum limit of unique permissions that can be set to a SharePoint list item without compromising its performance? The Custom list does not have too many look up columns but one custom column which adds documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum unique permission in a list is allowed **50,000** but as per Microsoft recommended is **5000**

[image: Maximum Unique Permission]

Reference Articles :

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0)

[SharePoint Permissions: Maximum number of unique permissions in a SharePoint library](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/maximum-number-of-unique-permissions-in-sharepoint-library/)

Answer (score 1):

The supported limit is 50,000, but the recommended general limit is 5,000. Making changes to more than 5,000 uniquely permissioned items at a time takes longer. For large lists, design to have as few unique permissions as possible.

As the number of unique permissions in a list increases, performance decreases. The throughput difference for operations on a list between 0 and 1,000 unique permissions is around 20 percent. I recommend that you consider lowering this limit to 5,000 unique permissions and for large lists consider using a design that uses as few unique permissions as possible. This will help not only performance, but also manageability.

[SharePoint limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

Comment: Is it also applicable for SharePoint online?

Comment: Yes, same 50 000 limit applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is already an old question, but the problem remains to this day!

“The supported limit of unique permissions for items in a list or library is 50,000. However, the recommended general limit is 5,000. Making changes to more than 5,000 uniquely permitted items at a time takes longer. Therefore, for large lists, design the list to have as few unique permissions as possible.”

References:

Sep 2023 - https://www.connecting-software.com/blog/overcoming-the-sharepoint-unique-permissions-limit/

Mar 2023 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/error-share-break-inheritance